# Regex Negation on part of word

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, regex-negation

I'm doing a regex search through about 20,000 HTML files using SublimeText and trying to find out of certain CSS classes exist or not. Unfortunately, some classes are similarly named and I want to ignore those ones. For example, I'm looking for files that contain the class "refine search" but not ones that contain "txt_refine_search".

I tried `refine_search(?!txt_refine_search)` but it still found "txt_refine_search".

What query should I be using?

Comment: Why are you using RegEx if you are trying to match an exact name?

Comment: This is just a small example, I have dozens of searches to do so I'm using regex to get through the list quicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example of `refine_search(?!txt_refine_search)` searches for `refine_search` followed by `txt_refine_search`.  As you found out, that won't work.

You may want to try a negative lookbehind.  Sublime Text uses the PCRE flavor of regex, which does support lookbehind statements.  It would look like `(?<!txt_)refine_search` and it would find `refine_search` not preceded by `txt_`.

Comment: Please edit your answer. There is no solution on it. I can see that it was a typo problem.

Comment: Done :) it was a problem with the &lt;

Comment: Thats great! Try to use the backticks next time! I've edited it! Take a look!

Comment: Nice answer.  You beat me to it :)  I took the liberty of clarifying your answer a little further.  Welcome to SO!  Hope to see you around in the future...

Comment: Thank you Steven, I started yesterday, see you around :)